# Android: what profiling tools are available under Eclipse to look at scalability?

Tags: android, eclipse, profiling

I am developing a piece of Java code to be run on Android. I did some testing to see how well it scales. I first ran the code on a Windows desktop and then on a 4.0 Android device. The latter scales very very poorly compared to the former. I need to figure out if there are some inefficiencies in my code that cause this. What profiling tool/plug-in would you recommend to run profiling both on the device and on the desktop to compare apples to apples? Thank you.

Comment: have you read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html?

Comment: @thinksteep: execution time as a function of input data size

Comment: @BG: No I have not, but I am not sure how relevant it is given my above definition of scalability. Thanks anyway though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did some testing to see how well it scales.

The term "scales" is usually used to refer to servers, that have to "scale" to lots of simultaneous users.

> What profiling tool/plug-in would you recommend to run profiling both on the device and on the desktop to compare apples to apples?

There is no such tool to the best of my knowledge.

If you feel that your Android code is not running efficiently enough, use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to see where your hot spots are.